# Transfer Learning problem with PyTorch, different data distributions range

Tags: pytorch

I'm wondering about the following thing:

I would like to apply some transfer learning on a project I'm working on using an Artificial Neural Network. I have two (chemical) datasets which have a different distribution of values but can be related from a physical point of view.

Having that the first quantity varies between 0 and 12 and the second between 10^{-13] and 10^{13}, how should I set up the network? Maybe with some intermediate normalization layer?

My initial attempt relies on building a first network in the following way:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features, h1, h2, out_features=1):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features,h1)    # input layer
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(h1, h2)            # hidden layer
        self.out = nn.Linear(h2, out_features)  # output layer
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.out(x)
        return x
```

After having trained this model for some epochs I would use the pre-trained weights to run over the other dataset that has different data distribution (between 10^{-13} and 10^{13}) but I'm not sure what kind of normalization, intermediate layer should I put before, to kinda **shift** the final way to match the other distribution..

Comment: Depends on the data. If being at the median value in dataset A is analogous to being at the median value in dataset B and similar relationships hold at other quintiles and locations in each dataset, you could use say batch normalization on the inputs layer or else manually normalize data with dataset statistics. However, if the desired output varies in different ways with the inputs for each dataset, such a method won't work well, and transfer learning may not be applicable.

Comment: I.e. you need to map your input into a space that will maintain the relationship between inputs and outputs across datasets, which may itself be nontrivial to learn.

Comment: But in general, you should attempt to "normalize" your data across datasets at the beginning of the network or before data is input, not in the middle or end of NN layers.